# C# Method inserts the same data again, when called again

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this method, which inserts data into `ChangeLog` table from GitLab API with data from all of the commits, now the problem is when I call it again from the API it inserts the same data again, making records go from 344 to 688.

```cs
private async Task PopulateChangeLogDataEntityRecursive(IEnumerable<AppVersionData> versions, IReadOnlyList<ChangeLogData> previousChangelog)
{
    var currentAppVersion = versions.FirstOrDefault();
    if (currentAppVersion == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var latestChangelog =
        previousChangelog.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AppVersion.Version == currentAppVersion.Version);
    if (latestChangelog != null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var previousVersions = versions.Skip(1);
    await PopulateChangeLogDataEntityRecursive(previousVersions, previousChangelog);

    var previousAppVersion = previousVersions.FirstOrDefault();
    if (previousAppVersion != null)
    {
        var changeLogDataList =
            await _gitLabClient.GetChangeLogData(previousAppVersion.Version, currentAppVersion.Version);
        foreach (var changeLogData in changeLogDataList)
        {
            changeLogData.AppVersionId = currentAppVersion.Id;
        }

        changeLogDataList = changeLogDataList.Where(cld => !previousChangelog.Any(pc => pc.Id == cld.Id))
            .ToList();
        if (changeLogDataList.Any())
        {
            await _repository.BulkInsertAsync(changeLogDataList);
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried is:

Before the `await _repository.BulkInsertAsync(changeLogDataList);` line, adding a condition to check if the data already exists in the previousChangelog.

Then inserting the data if there are new items in `changeLogDataList`

```cs
if (changeLogDataList.Any())
{
    await _repository.BulkInsertAsync(changeLogDataList);
}
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Entity Framework will often have an issue with multiple iterations of an IEnumerable.  Have you tried caching the versions into a List to ensure it's not queried more than once and see if that alleviates your issues?